# Changing Named Range Reference

Tags: excel, reference, named-ranges

I'm working with an Excel file that has a macro operation that generates a child file.  What I've been instructed to do is to create pick lists for some fields.  I created a new reference sheet in the parent file to house in drop down values.  Then I created named ranges for these columns.

The problem comes in when I perform the export operation of the child file.  The "Reference To" string changes to include the path of the parent file.  I don't want this because if the parent is closed, the pick list functionality in the child file breaks.

Is there a way to prevent the "Refers To" string from changing through the export process?  The reference sheet housing all the pick list info is copied over from parent to child.

I've tried referring to the cell ranges directly as well with the same results:

If the master file Refers To: ='Xref'!A2:A11
Then child file Refers TO is: ='[C:....xlsm]Xref'!A2:A11

Comment: Like `=INDIRECT("'Xref'!A2:A11",1)` would do?

Comment: I see two possibilities: 1) copy the whole workbook and thenodo whatever to create the child, or 2) do a find and replace on all the names in the new workbook.

Comment: Dirk, thank you for getting rid of my headache from having to putz around with this issue all day!

Your method works in both reference cases.  I ended up going with the named range option.  I entered in =INDIRECT("'Xref'!A2:A11").

Comment: @DirkReichel, this is a nice solution in it's way. Of course it's strength is also a possible pitfall: the fact that the names are no longer dynamic. They won't adjust if columns or rows are added or if the sheet name is changed. In addition, `INDIRECT` is volatile, which, depending on how many cells reference the names, could cause performance problems,

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the new workbook is a copy and contains all names like the original, you simply could run a `For Each` loop (used as macro in the source-workbook):

```
Dim xName As Variant, wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("the child workbook")
For Each xName In ThisWorkbook.Names
  wb.Names(xName.Name).RefersToR1C1 = xName.RefersToR1C1
Next
```

And if not all names exist, just use the `On Error Resume Next` in front of the loop :)

If you still have any questions, just ask.

**EDIT**
if not all names exist in the new wb, then this will be better/faster (used as macro in the source-workbook):

```
Dim xName As Variant, wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("the child workbook")
For Each xName In wb.Names
  xName.RefersToR1C1 = ThisWorkbook.Names(xName.Name).RefersToR1C1
Next
```